# NotFoundHttpException in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel and I am having some issues. NotFoundHttpException is coming up when I am trying to access a URL like [domain]/user/1

From what I've been researching on this, it clearly means that the route cannot be found. I do not see any errors with my code though and it looks like the route should be found.

The Route:

```
Route::get('user/(:any)', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getView'));
```

The Controller:

```
public function getView($id) {
    return View::make('users.view',
        [
            'title' => 'User View Page',
            'user' => User::find($id)
        ]
    );
}
```

The View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $user -> user }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $user -> bio }}</p>
@stop
```

I have mod_rewrite on.
Why can this route not find a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Laravel 4, this is how you should create the route:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getView'));
```

Comment: Works perfectly now.. This is the issue with using outdated resources I guess. Many thanks. Looks like this is a resource I should be using http://wiki.laravel.io/Changelog_(Laravel_4)